# Android Studio. How to save compileSDK for future projects

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

My question is related to the `build.gradle.kts` Module:app file.
For every new project I have to enter the **`compileSdk`** manually. Is there a way to save this permanently? I actually can't find anything on Google. In `Project Structure` there doesn't seem to be a way either

```
android {
    namespace = "com.wolfcard.roomone"
    compileSdk = 34 // <------------------- save this fix for another projects

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.wolfcard.roomone"
        minSdk = 27
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are certainly welcome to have your Gradle scripts read in data from external files, such as a properties file. That data could include values for `compileSdk`. However, you really need to think through how this file ties into your overall version control strategy (e.g., what you commit to a git repository). Also, you really need to consider whether these projects should *be* separate projects, rather than separate modules in a single project, if they are this closely tied.